# can I do "onClick" function in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I made html page where you click and activate function by the id of html-element.
It took me many lines in javascript. can I short the by a for loop?

this is my html code:

```
<ul>    
    <li class="card" id="c0"><img id="i0" src="images\westren_wall.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c1"><img id="i1" src="images\westren_wall.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c2"><img id="i2" src="images\idf.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c3"><img id="i3" src="images\idf.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c4"><img id="i4" src="images\jerusalem.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c5"><img id="i5" src="images\jerusalem.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c6"><img id="i6" src="images\sixDays.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c7"><img id="i7" src="images\sixDays.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c8"><img id="i8" src="images\BGurion.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c9"><img id="i9" src="images\BGurion.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c10"><img id="i10" src="images\hertzel.png"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c11"><img id="i11" src="images\hertzel.png"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c12"><img id="i12" src="images\vaizman.png"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c13"><img id="i13" src="images\vaizman.png"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c14"><img id="i14" src="images\menora.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c15"><img id="i15" src="images\menora.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c16"><img id="i16" src="images\knesset.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c17"><img id="i17" src="images\knesset.jpg"></li>
```

I use it do active a function when clicking by this javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("c0").onclick = function(){openCard("i0",1)};
    document.getElementById("c1").onclick = function(){openCard("i1", 1)};
    document.getElementById("c2").onclick = function(){openCard("i2",2)};   
    document.getElementById("c3").onclick = function(){openCard("i3",2)};
    document.getElementById("c4").onclick = function(){openCard("i4",3)};
    document.getElementById("c5").onclick = function(){openCard("i5",3)};
    document.getElementById("c6").onclick = function(){openCard("i6",4)};
    document.getElementById("c7").onclick = function(){openCard("i7",4)};
    document.getElementById("c8").onclick = function(){openCard("i8",5)};
    document.getElementById("c9").onclick = function(){openCard("i9",5)};
    document.getElementById("c10").onclick = function(){openCard("i10",6)};
    document.getElementById("c11").onclick = function(){openCard("i11",6)};
    document.getElementById("c12").onclick = function(){openCard("i12",7)};
    document.getElementById("c13").onclick = function(){openCard("i13",7)};
    document.getElementById("c14").onclick = function(){openCard("i14",8)};
    document.getElementById("c15").onclick = function(){openCard("i15",8)};
    document.getElementById("c16").onclick = function(){openCard("i16",9)};
    document.getElementById("c17").onclick = function(){openCard("i17",9)};
```

can I short this code lines by a for loop?

Comment: How about giving those elements a common class, binding an on click to the class and then reading the id in that event before calling opencard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a custom attribute on your every `img` element like `data-img-index` ,then you can set click event on every classname with value **card**. Finally get the `id` and custom attribute value i.e `data-img-index` like this way to pass on your `openCard(id, attr);` method

**Id:** `var id = this.children[0].id;`

**Custom Attr:** `var attr = this.children[0].attributes['data-img-index'].nodeValue;`

```js
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("card");

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
  classname[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var id = this.children[0].id;
    var attr = this.children[0].attributes['data-img-index'].nodeValue;
    openCard(id, attr);
  });
}

function openCard(id, num) {
  console.log(id, num)
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="card" id="c0"><img id="i0" data-img-index=1 src="images\westren_wall.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c1"><img id="i1" data-img-index=1 src="images\westren_wall.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c2"><img id="i2" data-img-index=2 src="images\idf.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c3"><img id="i3" data-img-index=2 src="images\idf.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c4"><img id="i4" data-img-index=3 src="images\jerusalem.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c5"><img id="i5" data-img-index=3 src="images\jerusalem.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c6"><img id="i6" data-img-index=4 src="images\sixDays.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c7"><img id="i7" data-img-index=4 src="images\sixDays.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c8"><img id="i8" data-img-index=5 src="images\BGurion.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c9"><img id="i9" data-img-index=5 src="images\BGurion.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c10"><img id="i10" data-img-index=6 src="images\hertzel.png"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c11"><img id="i11" data-img-index=6 src="images\hertzel.png"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c12"><img id="i12" data-img-index=7 src="images\vaizman.png"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c13"><img id="i13" data-img-index=7 src="images\vaizman.png"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c14"><img id="i14" data-img-index=8 src="images\menora.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c15"><img id="i15" data-img-index=8 src="images\menora.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c16"><img id="i16" data-img-index=9 src="images\knesset.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c17"><img id="i17" data-img-index=9 src="images\knesset.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it way easier:

```
for(var i = 0;i <= 17;i++){
    document.getElementById("c" + i).onclick = function(){
        openCard("i" + i, Math.floor(i / 2) + 1);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is via event delegation: Hook `click` on the `ul`, and then use `e.target` to refer to the specific `img` that was clicked. Store any information you need on that element:

```
<ul id="list">    
    <li class="card" id="c0"><img data-card="i0" data-index="0" src="images\westren_wall.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c1"><img data-card="i1" data-index="0" src="images\westren_wall.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c2"><img data-card="i2" data-index="1" src="images\idf.jpg"></li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Then just one handler:

```
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    openCard(e.target.getAttribute("data-card"), +e.target.getAttribute("data-index"));
});
```

Or if you prefer `.onclick` (but there's no reason to unless you have to support truly obsolete browsers like IE8):

```
document.getElementById("list").onclick = function(e) {
    openCard(e.target.getAttribute("data-card"), +e.target.getAttribute("data-index"));
};
```

Live Example:

```js
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    openCard(e.target.getAttribute("data-card"), +e.target.getAttribute("data-index"));
});

function openCard(card, index) {
  console.log("card = " + card + ", index = " + index);
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">    
    <li class="card" id="c0"><img data-card="i0" data-index="0" src="images\westren_wall.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c1"><img data-card="i1" data-index="0" src="images\westren_wall.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card" id="c2"><img data-card="i2" data-index="1" src="images\idf.jpg"></li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

---

Actually, taking another look at the markup, you don't need `data-card` at all; it's the parent element of the `img`, so:

```
<ul id="list">    
    <li class="card"><img data-index="0" src="images\westren_wall.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card"><img data-index="0" src="images\westren_wall.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card"><img data-index="1" src="images\idf.jpg"></li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

and

```
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    openCard(e.target.parentNode, +e.target.getAttribute("data-index"));
});
```

...where you'd change `openCard` so it expects the element itself, not an `id`.

Live example:

```js
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    openCard(e.target.parentNode, +e.target.getAttribute("data-index"));
});

function openCard(element, index) {
  // use `element` and `index` here, the following code is just for the demo:
  element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" opened, index = " + index));
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">    
    <li class="card"><img data-card="i0" data-index="0" src="images\westren_wall.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card"><img data-card="i1" data-index="0" src="images\westren_wall.jpg"></li>
    <li class="card"><img data-card="i2" data-index="1" src="images\idf.jpg"></li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can auto-generate both your HTML and your JavaScript.

I've used jQuery in my example but you can achieve this in plain JavaScript as well.

```js
// Generate your html
// Only specify the pictures you want to display
// The pictures are the only differences you have on your <li>
const data = [
  'images\westren_wall.jpg',
  'image2',
  'image3',
  'image4',
  'image5',
].map((x, xi) => `<li class="card" id="c${xi}"><img id="i${xi}" src="${x}"></li>`);

// Insert it into the page at the right position
$("#myData").html(data);

// trigger the clicks for each <li> having the card class
$('.card').each(function(x) {
  $(this).click(function() {
    // It will say hi when you i'll click on a <li>!
    console.log(`Hi i'm number ${this.getAttribute('id')}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="myData">
   <!-- Where the <li> are gonna get inserted -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could write a loop to attach all those handlers. But it's easier to just put one onclick handler on the *ul* that contains all the *li*s. When a click happens, Javascript will looks for handlers all the way up the list of ancestor elements (there's more to it, too, but that's close enough for the moment).

The handler can then look at the original "target" element, to figure out exactly what parameters to pass to your opencard() function. You could put the parameter values somewhere on that element (probably in an attribute, so you could get them with getAttribute()), or your handler might be able to just calculate them. In your example, you could calculate the first parameter just by getting the ID of the target element and changing "c" to "i"), and the second parameter by a little arithmetic.